# Database Design - Assignment Submission

Tags: database-design

I am currently doing a personal project where its aimed to help students and teachers. One of the module I planned was Assignment submission system. However I don't know how to start with that since this is my first time taking such a huge project for myself.

Here are the details

1. Every Course have one assignment
2. Each students can only submit the assignment once and they can only submit the assignments of the class they are enrolled in.
3. Theres a dateline for submission
4. Only the teacher can view the assignments.

Currently

I have two tables that I know will be use in the module which is

```
**users**
userID
username
password
emailaddress

**course**
course_id
course_name
course_description
```

I'm guessing I'll need a table called assignments and teachers too.

```
**assignments**
assignment_id
assignment_description
assignment_due

**assignments_submitted**
submit_ID
assignment_ID foreign key with assignments.assignment_ID
studentID foreign key with students.StudentID
time
marks

**teachers**
teach_id
teach_course Foreign key with course_id
```

But thats about it that I can visualize since this is my first time playing around with databases, I would love some input from you guys if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing connecting courses and assignments - I would put the course_id as a foreign key in assignments so that if the '1 assignment per course' rule ever changed your database schema would stay the same.

Since there is a many-to-many relationship between users and courses you will need an association class.

Otherwise looks like pretty much like the standard way to build a database for an academic institution.